# How to programmatically turn on/off "Receive incoming calls" for SIP on Android

Tags: android, sip, accounts

On Android 2.3+ there is a switch `Receive incoming calls` (in Call Settings / Internet call settings / Accounts). How to turn on/off this switch programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Not so difficult , if you use a Free App from Google Play:

- Install the "Any Cut" application from Google Market (free)
  [Any Cut](http://tinyurl.com/bofo4q2)
- Then, Run "Any Cut" on your device and choose:
  "New Short-cut" -> "Activity" -> "SIP Settings" -> and create the new short-cut
  That's it!
  Now on your desktop you can find a new short-cut to "receive incoming calls"

quite easy! ;-)

Comment: This doesnt answer the question